# El mainloop no termina

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo 2 clases, para el inicio de sesión utilizo `tkinter` para hacer la ventana, tiene una función que cuando se inicia sesión correctamente, cierra la ventana y abre otra que utiliza otra libreria llamada `customtkinter`, todo bien solo que cuando cierro esta ventana noté que la terminal siguia corriendo.

```
class login:

     def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Inicio de Sesión")
        self.root.configure(bg="#323232")
        
  
    def ventana_iniciar_sesion(self):

        #codigo

    def verificar_credenciales(self, usuario, contrasena):

        #codigo

    def ventana_registrarse(self):
        #codigo
        
    def registrar_usuario(self, usuario, contrasena):
          
        #codigo

    def abrir_aplicacion_principal(self):
        self.root.destroy()  # Cerrar la ventana de inicio de sesión
        app = CTk()
        app = ProcesoContratacionApp(app)

class ProcesoContratacionApp():

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = CTk()  
        self.app.geometry("400x240")

        
        button = CTkButton(master=self.app, text="CTkButton", command=self.button_function)
        button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.app.mainloop()

    def button_function(self):
        print("button pressed")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root_login = tk.Tk()
    root_login_login = login(root_login)
    root_login.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Como regla de oro en tkinter (y por extensión en customtkinter), nunca debes tener mas de una instancia de `tkinter.Tk` (o `customtkinter.CTk`) de forma concurrente, y aun menos ejecutar mas de un mainloop simultáneamente.

En `abrir_aplicacion_principal` estas creando una instancia de `customtkinter.CTk` que pasas a  `ProcesoContratacionApp`. El problema es que en vez de usar esta instancia como root, en  el inicializador de `ProcesoContratacionApp` creas otra instancia de `customtkinter.CTk`.

Deberías hacer:

```
    def abrir_aplicacion_principal(self):
        self.root.destroy()  # Cerrar la ventana de inicio de sesión
        app = CTk()
        ProcesoContratacionApp(app)


class ProcesoContratacionApp():

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app  
        self.app.geometry("400x240")
```

o bien:

```
    def abrir_aplicacion_principal(self):
        self.root.destroy()  # Cerrar la ventana de inicio de sesión
        ProcesoContratacionApp()

class ProcesoContratacionApp():

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = CTk()  
        self.app.geometry("400x240")
```

Pero no una mezcla de ambas.

---

Dicho esto, aunque crear una ventana principal para el login, destruirla y luego generar otra ventana principal para la app pueda funcionar, no es la forma recomendada de proceder en este tipo de casos. Lo recomendable es usar una sola ventana principal y su mainloop que se mantengan vivos durante toda la ejecución y para el resto de cosas usar `tkinter.Toplevel` (o `customtkinter.CTkToplevel`) para gestionar nuevas ventanas, ocultando o mostrando la ventana principal según convenga.

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk


class Login(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        parent.withdraw()
        self.title("Inicio de Sesión")
        self.configure(bg="#323232")
        
        self.geometry("400x240")
        tk.Button(
            self, text='Login',
            command=self.abrir_aplicacion_principal
            ).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    def abrir_aplicacion_principal(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.parent.deiconify()        


class ProcesoContratacionApp(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        button = ctk.CTkButton(master=self, text="CTkButton", command=self.button_function)
        button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=ctk.CENTER)
        Login(self.parent)        

    def button_function(self):
        print("button pressed")
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = ctk.CTk()
    root.geometry("400x240")
    ProcesoContratacionApp(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Puedes mezclar widgets de tkinter y customtkinter sin problemas, aunque si no hay una razón de peso para usar tkinter plano en la ventana de login, por consistencia seria recomendable que usaras customtkinter en todo.